# Incorrect datetime value

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am trying to fill my table with data but I am having trouble with the datetimes (Incorrect datetime value error). My data is in this format `2017-08-30 10:00:00-07:00`.

What kind of transformation is needed so that I can insert the right time in my database?

Here's an example which is not working. I am using MySQL 5.6.10

```
INSERT INTO table (id, created_at)  
VALUES (89208460, "2017-08-30 10:00:00-07:00");
```

Running `SELECT NOW()` gives me `2017-09-27 11:47:38`, it's a `DATETIME(19)` field.

Comment: Providing the table definition might be useful. Have you tried removing the timezone value?

Answer (score 1):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

> Running `SELECT NOW()` gives me `2017-09-27 11:47:38`, it's a `DATETIME(19)` field.

Not `(19)`, the number is the number of decimal places in the seconds.

> What kind of transformation is needed so that I can insert the right time in my database?

MySQL has no concept of time zone representation.

That is there is no way to use (read or write) `-07:00`.